# Not enough space on /tmp

Tags: filesystem, update-manager, tmp

I'm not able to run update manager as I get an error saying that there is not enough free space in the `/tmp` directory. I've practically cleaned out the `tmp` directory but the error persists.

here's `df-h`

```
/dev/loop0       13G   11G  952M  92% /
udev            2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           785M  920K  784M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G  584K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda6        20G   14G  6.4G  68% /host

overflow        1.0M   16K 1008K   2% /tmp
```

Comment: where is your / ? Why is it on a /dev/loop ?

Comment: Here, a simple reboot solved the issue. As @josinalvo explained, `/` was full and was increased on the fly: The disk was a virtual disk.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

What seems to have happened:

Your `/` was full, then Ubuntu created a new partition, in RAM memory, to use temporarily.

Now, this 1**MB** partition is not big enough for the job, either.

What we can do:

1) increase the size of this partition just to do the upgrade

2) actually delete enough files in the HD that this partition is no longer needed.

---

**To do 1:**

open a terminal and run

```
sudo umount /tmp
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=1048576,mode=1777 overflow /tmp
```

This should give you an 1MB partition (just like the one you had =P).

Now, to increase the size, you increase the `size` in that line, so that, with `size=10485760`, you'd get 10 MB.

Your goal is to find a number that is enough for the job, but leaves enough ram too

**Comments on 1**

You may want to try `sudo umount -l /tmp`, if you get some variation of "the file system is busy and cannot be unmounted"

Another possible solution to "the file system s busy(...)" is to do `fuser -m /tmp` to find pids (process numbers) that are using /tmp, then `ps -elf <pids>`, stop or kill processes

You may want to try `sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=1MB,mode=1777 overflow /tmp` or even `sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=1G,mode=1777 overflow /tmp` (for 1 megabyte or 1 gigabyte, respectively) - that is, units are available so that you dont have to type a huge number

---

**To do 2:**

Open a terminal and run `sudo umount /tmp` or, if that fails, `sudo umount -l /tmp`.

Then clean up!

Delete files in `/tmp` (**now** `/tmp` is the thing actually in your HD, rather than a virtual ram disk), uninstall unused packages, delete files in your home folder and so on.

Comment: This answer worked for me but I needed to kill some things before /tmp would umount. If you get a message that says /tmp is busy, then do `fuser -m /tmp` to find pids that are using /tmp, then `ps -elf <pids>`, stop or kill processes. Then umount /tmp. Also suggested on internet `sudo umount overflow`.

Comment: @gaoithe I used `sudo lsof | grep tmp` to find the pid then `kill` to kill it. In my case this was Xorg. This is the X Window System which I don't use anyways.

Comment: To do 2 even simpler: after cleanup just reboot. This avoids problems with `umount /tmp` because of a being busy.

Comment: May i know why you have reverted back my edits?

Comment: Thank you for your improvements on my answer! (but some, I did not like and removed)

Comment: Too many processes to fool around with on a live web server, so I followed @Roland's suggestion to reboot (sudo shutdown -r now). As a side benefit  I gained back 10G on a 40G file system - although that may have been from rebuilding db tables (mysql "optimize") I did just to be sure.

Comment: Actually, I failed to `umount` this tmpfs by all above ways. 
I googled `umount -l /tmp` and it helped.

Comment: The instruction under 'to do 2' worked for me. With Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. This issue came about after updating a kernel images. I have removed unused kernel images following https://superuser.com/a/1042344/491642

Comment: use size with G or MB with all above, and it will work.

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo mount -o remount,size=1048576 /tmp
```

changes `tmpfs` size without need to unmount partition and hence not disturbing running apps.

Answer (score 7):

I know about this problem on my Kubuntu 16.04, and user63070 shows the best answer. Change the size at /etc/fstab like this:

```
tmpfs     /tmp     tmpfs     defaults,size=10G,mode=1777     0     0
```

Reboot, and you got 10GB for your /tmp folder.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your / partition is full.

If you have space on other partitions on your disk, you might use this space to increase the size of your / partition. There are tools available for this, for example gparted.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

http://gparted.sourceforge.net

Comment: is there a 'safer' tool, apparently gparted is kinda tricky to handle especially for noobs

Comment: It is very tricky, and not the easiest way to address the problem. I would not venture using it for this

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure @user220420 was referring to /etc/fstab instead of /etc/mtab. I had lots of free GB in my root, however, Firefox wouldn't let me download anything from the internet. A small window would pop-up before finishing any download, telling /tmp had not enough space left. Within fstab, there's this line where you can increase tmp's folder size. It was set to 100M so I changed it to 1000M. After reboot, I right-clicked on /tmp (in root) and properties showed 1GB free (to make sure changes applied properly). That was it.

Comment: Let me tell you that this worked with other distros other than Ubuntu. I could accomplish this on Sabayon as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you install your Ubuntu with default LVM settings nowadays, your LV size might be to low. Run:

```
df -h
```

and check if `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` is full (about 100%). If so, run:

```
sudo lvdisplay
```

to get the actual size of your LV. If you have space left more than that, you can allocate it by:

```
sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
```

This will then use all available disk space. Extend the filesystem afterwards to use the new disk space:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

Answer (score -1):

Open up /etc/mtab in your favorite text editor with root privledges (ie “sudo vim /etc/mtab”). And increase the memory allocated to your /tmp folder. After restart Ubuntu will increase the space to /tmp, and fix this problem.

Comment: 1) You don't edit `/etc/mtab` - that file is handled by `mount`, 2) there is probably no entry fo `/tmp` in `etc/fstab` either.