# /tmp running out of space, can't umount /tmp to cleanup (device busy)

Tags: partitioning, ppa, update-manager, gparted

When I tried installing VLC plugin libde265 , I got this error message

```
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I also keep getting that /tmp is out of disk space.
What should I do?
Here's output of df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.9G   12K  2.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           583M  1.5M  582M   1% /run
/dev/sda7        43G   29G   12G  72% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.9G   53M  2.8G   2% /run/shm
none            100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user
overflow        1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /tmp
/dev/sda5       385G  118G  267G  31% /media/shashank/F0007F2C007EF944
```

On using the command

```
sudo umount /tmp
```

I get

```
umount: /tmp: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
```

Since earlier questions were just solved by running the above command,I am posting a new question about this find out any remedies if possible

Comment: There are two ways to sole this, see the answer in http://askubuntu.com/a/199708/425087

Comment: sudo umount  /tmp is not working for me

Comment: You need to remount the real temp afterwards.  what is the output to `blkid`?