# How to specify a temporary folder with more disk space via terminal?

Tags: command-line, files, disk

I need more disk space at /tmp and /usr folders. How will achieve this?

An error appeared:

```
root@kali:/home/Downloads# ./netbeans-8.1-linux.sh
Configuring the installer...
Cannot create temporary directory /tmp/.nbi-5055107.tmp
```

Comment: Hi Morpheus, did you see the duplicate link that was posted on your other question ? It addresses resizing /tmp

Comment: --tempdir (installer argument)

Comment: No! Never duplicate a question..

Comment: what do u mean by "Never duplicate a question"????

Comment: to @Mohit Rajan: < How can specify a temporary folder with sufficient disk space via terminal? > This question is not duplicate.

Comment: Do u have the /tmp as a different partition??

Comment: No. The path is typically: /tmp

Comment: It's not a duplicate because /tmp is not necessarily a separate partition. Serg's answer does not appear in the supposed duplicate question.

Comment: @wjandrea the actual duplicate is indeed different - I've already mentioned that post in my answer

Comment: What's your current partitioning scheme? Can you please include the output of `lsblk`, and `sudo parted -l` in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's couple of ways you can go about this:

#### #1, remount /tmp with bigger size

As shown in  [Update failing. Not enough space on /tmp](https://askubuntu.com/q/199565/295286)

```
sudo umount /tmp
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=16777216,mode=1777 overflow /tmp
```

That will give you 16 MB in`/mpt` . Adjust `size=` to how much you need

#### #2, make temporary directory in your home

```
$ mktemp -d -p $HOME                                                 
/home/xieerqi/tmp.zrBHbp0Yt0
```

That will make temporary directory in your `$HOME` folder, that means you can use as much space as you need