# Unmount second SSD from /tmp

Tags: partitioning, mount, ssd

My PC has two SSDs (120GB and 465GB), the smaller SSD is mounted on / and currently the larger SSD is mounted on /tmp. Output of `df -h`:

```
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             12G     0   12G   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.4G  114M  2.3G   5% /run
/dev/sda1       101G   88G  8.1G  92% /
tmpfs            12G  130M   12G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            12G     0   12G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb5       459G   73M  435G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           2.4G  112K  2.4G   1% /run/user/1001
```

I have quite limited experience in doing this so I'm just looking for the easiest way of re-allocating space from the larger SSD to / or to /home from /tmp.

(Note: I didn't create this set-up myself, there was a previous user who mounted the drives in this way.)

`fdisk -l` output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 214843391 214841344 102.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       214845438 250068991  35223554  16.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       214845440 250068991  35223552  16.8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2046 976771071 976769026 465.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5        2048 976771071 976769024 465.8G 83 Linux
```

Comment: this is easily done if your setup had used different format options (eg. lvm). in your case I'd just boot a live usb-thumb drive (eg. ubuntu install media) and copy directories such as /home to the second drive (after `cp` has completed; I'd `diff` to ensure they copied correctly; then `rm` only if you're happy; yes you could `mv` but the added `diff` compare step makes me happier).  then modify your `/etc/fstab` to reflect your new chosen layout & reboot your normal ubuntu os.

Answer (score 0):

First unmount the sdb5

```
sudo umount /tmp
```

then mount it to your home directory  using:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb5 /home
```

refer to mapages of `mount` for more details.

Comment: before I did that; I'd copy the data you want from your existing home, to a directory on the larger SSD, and then mount that directory as your new $HOME.  the reason for this is the newer mount will overshadow your existing $HOME & any files there will become hidden (ie. you can't access them when the larger SSD is mounted as $HOME).

Comment: It doesn't allow me to `umount /tmp` as the device is busy. I tried killing the processes on /tmp as suggested here https://askubuntu.com/questions/199565/not-enough-space-on-tmp, but killing the processes logs me out.