# /tmp/ is somehow out of space and contains an irremovable file

Tags: command-line, permissions

When tab-autocompleting in terminal, I'm getting the error:

```
-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
```

This would appear to mean that `/tmp/` is full, but it's mounted ***on my hard disk***, which itself has lots of space left.

`/tmp` only contains one thing: a folder called `/tmp/.mount_VCeNjK/`. 
I can't find out anything about it, because even `sudo` and `su` can't `chmod` it, read it, `umount` it, `rm` it, or `stat` it. They complain about permissions and say that it's busy.

What can I do? I'm nothing without my autocomplete.

Comment: `/tmp` is usually mounted in memory since it's `tmpfs` filesystem. Run `df` command, see what's the actual usage  it reports. You can further analyze what takes up most memory via `ncdu` or just `du` running over `/tmp`. There's also a way to increase `/tmp` size: https://askubuntu.com/a/199708/295286

Comment: `sudo lsof +D /tmp/.mount_VCeNjK/` will show you which processes have the directory (or files and directories underneath) open. When these processes finish (or are `kill`ed), you'll probably be able to `sudo rm -rf`. But be aware that this will have side effects that I can't predict, so you MUST proceed with care.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Most Linux systems don't actually mount `/tmp` using tmpfs, see `mount | grep tmp` for an example.

Comment: @KristopherIves  Fair enough, but I wouldn't say "most", I'd say "some" do ([also this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30504/85039) ). As far as Ubuntu goes, I had `/tmp` mounted as tmpfs in previous releases of Ubuntu, hence assuming it's default. Could have happened that I  mounted it there myself at some point, but I don't recall doing so. There's apparently discussion on [centos forum](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=47063) which suggests it may depend on amount of RAM

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy never been default in Ubuntu indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible (although not common) for a ext4 file system to have remaining space but nothing reserved for inode meta data, essentially meaning the disk is "full" of a very large (millions) of small individual files.

You can run `df -i` to see the "IUse%" metric of a file system.

Comment: This did it, thanks. Some folders in /var/log and /var/lib/motion had slowly been filling up